# After updating GCC, Clang can't find libstdc++ anymore

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

After updating GCC to a newer version,

```
$sudo apt-get install gcc-10
```

I cannot compile C++ with Clang anymore. What is a way to fix this?

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

Ubuntu version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Trying to compile a basic helloworld program:

```
$ clang++ helloworld.cpp -v
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name helloworld.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -fno-rounding-math -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info -fno-split-dwarf-inlining -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++ -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/username/project.simplefem/tests/basic -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o /tmp/helloworld-315ed2.o -x c++ helloworld.cpp
clang -cc1 version 10.0.0 based upon LLVM 10.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
helloworld.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

'gcc' itself seems to refer to the gcc-9 version nevertheless:

```
$gcc -v 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-HskZEa/gcc-9-9.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
```

Comment: Q: What platform are you running (e.g. Ubunutu 18.05)? Q: How exactly did you "update gcc"? Q: What is the current g++ version (e.g. output of  `g++ -v`)? Please "Edit" your post and copy/paste this information.

Comment: @paulsm4: okay, here is what I got.

Comment: OK:  I think this the problem: `sudo apt-get install gcc-10`.  It looks like you installed the C compiler (gcc), not the C++ compiler (g++): https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-g-the-c-compiler-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: Have you tried to install `g++-10 `?

Comment: Have you tried to use `update-alternatives` to update the alternatives system?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin: I was *hoping* the OP would read the link I cited (I know: wishful thinking on my part).  Anyway, I'd recommend `sudo apt install build-essential` as my "first choice".

Comment: With Clang 14 / Ubuntu 22.04, I was getting the OP error, `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++`. It was happening in the CMake level so I didn't get the opportunity to try to compile for further errors. I had some version of `gcc` / `g++` already installed as well as `build-essentials`, but what fixed it for me in my environment was installing `gcc-12` & `g++-12`

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure that your highest version of g++ is same as your highest version of gcc.
For example, you installed gcc-10, gcc-11, and g++-10 in your system, this error will occur. g++-11 can be installed to fix this problem.

Here is my reference:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211743/clang-doesnt-find-c-stdlib-on-my-ubuntu-18-04-but-it-does-on-a-brand-new-ins

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 22.04.
The gcc and g++ versions are both the same (11.3.0)

I think the broken upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 was incomplete.

The /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu directory contained a '12' directory.
However most of the libraries are missing in this dir.

I simply removed the 12 directory. Now clang++ picks '11'
and everything works correctly

Comment: It works as a quick hack, but you should reinstall the system if you botched an upgrade. Or at least reinstall the offending package.

Comment: You are right. I did the upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 and it crashed before it finished.
I did something to fix it then but I guess some parts are still broken

Comment: This seemed to recreate what clang needed for me, after experiencing the same problem: sudo apt reinstall libstdc++-12-dev

Comment: my problem was I'd accidentally installed a gcc-12 package, hence the additional directory

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20. At some point (probably after some updates) clang failed to find std libraries. Using `-stdlib=libc++` what will use clang standard library instead of gcc, `libstdc++`. Actually compiled the whole llvm, because the distro package was quite old. Scripts is [here](https://github.com/ChoppinBlockParty/Yuki-s-.files/blob/af18cc6fe8a8ecae118cf03c7ea5b374418cfca6/install-llvm.sh).

**UPDATE**
Use [LLVM repo](https://apt.llvm.org/) to get binaries.

Comment: You can get the latest prebuilt Clang for Ubuntu here: https://apt.llvm.org/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That is sweet! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev`